# Blender 2.82 Fluid Simulation can't resume baking

Tags: fluid-simulation, cache, experimental-features

I have simulated a pool of water and was baking the mesh for the water. My system crashed and I could not resume baking. I backed the mesh folder up and freed the mesh. I put the files back in place but could not resume it would always start over and replace the old files. (The same happened for the simulation but i'm tired of running it all over again)

> Anyone got an idea how to resume baking?

I'm running the blender alpha build from 05.01.2019

Answer (score 1):

Blender does not support fluid bakes that can be re-started from a different frame. However, in mantaflow, this *is* supported. You might want to consider installing mantaflow for blender unless you are already use it. (It would be weird if you are since you cannot restart your fluid bake.) You can download mantaflow [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/branches/).